# Firefox Tab Stop between Address Bar and Search Bar

Tags: firefox, user-interface

I commonly use `TAB` to move from the address bar to the search box in Firefox.  However, I just recently noticed that it has started stopping at all the toolbar buttons in between rather than going directly between the two.  I nearly certain it doesn't do this on my other PC (don't have it handy right now, but I'm pretty sure it is also on the latest FF).  Was there a recent change to this behavior, or is Firefox on my home computer suddenly configured differently?

I am using Firefox 67.0 (64-bit).

Comment: tab order should flow from top-left -> bottom-right, for webpages in western-based languages, just as a general design principal. For me, the addition of the "View" toggle feature ("Toggle Reader View") puts an extra tab between the address bar and Search on FF 67.0.  you can see if disabling it has any effect: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1065043 . Also note, that reader view is not available on every page of every site (I don't see it on DDG), so the discrepancy may just be the content in question.

Comment: Thanks for the response; prior to version 67, I didn't hit any stops between the address bar and the search box, regardless of how many buttons appeared there.

Comment: to move to the search bar you can simply use Ctrl+K or Ctrl+E

Comment: @phuclv - thank you, I was aware of and occasionally use `Ctrl+K`, but somehow my brain is currently wired to do `Alt+D` then `TAB` often enough that this was becoming an annoyance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable this you need to set `browser.toolbars.keyboard_navigation` to `false`.

> And now, the setting:
>
> (1) In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button promising to be careful or accepting the risk.
>
> (2) In the search box above the list, type or paste TOOLB and pause while the list is filtered
>
> (3) Double-click the browser.toolbars.keyboard_navigation preference to switch the value from true to false

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1260534

Comment: you are a scholar ant a gentleman (or woman).  That worked perfectly--accepted the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I verified that my other PC this morning that is NOT exhibiting this behavior is on Firefox 66.0.4.  Thus, I decided I should look over the [version 67 release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/67.0/releasenotes/).  From there, I found the following referenced link:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/access-toolbar-functions-using-keyboard

According to that page, this is a new feature to allow full keyboard accessibility to all toolbar elements.  So, this is a new feature; just not one that worked for me!

Unless/until I find a way to disable this, I'll go ahead and accept this answer.